# Add Custom Colors in Color Palette of CEWP in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding

We have a requirement to incorporate custom colors used by the client in color palette (shown on edit of CEWP - see attached image) of a SharePoint Online site. We see that we can edit the last 6 slots of the color palette by changing the 'ContentAccent1' to 'ContentAccent6' values in .SPCOLOR file of Themes galley, creating a new theme using the new .SPCOLOR file in Composed Looks and applying the new theme on the site. However we have requirement to add more than 6 custom colors & their shades in the color palette. Has anyone come across this type of requirement and is there an way to achieve it?

Also we see that in Microsoft PPT 2016 file, we can add our own custom 'color section' in the color palette by modifying .XML file of the theme. In SharePoint (from 2013 version onwards), there is no provision to modify the theme file directly (its linked through .SPFONT & .SPCOLOR files through Composed Looks). Is there any way to add such custom colors section in the color palette of SharePoint online site?

Thanks,
Aashish[image]